# React - function inside of a loop just gets called once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, loops

I have a click handler in my book component that flips pages or more accurately it appends the required classnames to the pages, so i can set the css for the page flip animation.

```
  // ---------- Handle the click event on the book pages ---------- //

  const handleClick = async (page) => {
    // left page
    if (page === currentPage - 1 && page >= 2) {
      setFlippedPages((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        [page]: "forward",
        [page - 1]: "forward",
      }));

      // Wait for the page flip transition to be half complete
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 450));
      setCurrentPage(page - 1);
    }
    // right page
    else if (page === currentPage) {
      setFlippedPages((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        [page]: "backward",
        [page + 1]: "backward",
      }));

      // Wait for the page flip transition to be half complete
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 450));
      setCurrentPage(page + 2);
    }
  };
```

when a user want to, for example go to page 45 I use the turnPages function

```
// ---------- Turn Pages ---------- //

  const turnPages = async (page) => {
    for (let i = 2; i < page; i += 2) {
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 900)); // Wait for 900ms
      console.log(i);
      handleClick(i);
    }
  };
```

the function does the iteration of 45 page in steps of 2 at the right delay of 900ms, but unfortunately the handleClick just get called once in the first iteration.

I tried multiple other approaches like :

```
  const turnPages = (page) => {
    for (let i = 2; i < page; i += 2) {
      setTimeout(
        (i) => {
          handleClick(i);
          console.log(i);
        },
        900 * (i / 2),
        i
      );
    }
  };
```

or

```
  const turnPages = (page) => {
    const delayedClick = (i) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        handleClick(i);
        console.log(i);
        if (i + 2 < page) {
          delayedClick(i + 2);
        }
      }, 900);
    };

    delayedClick(2);
  };
```

I also returned a Promise inside the handleClick function to make sure the function has completed before moving to the next iteration. Which didn't do any difference.

```
  // ---------- Handle the click event on the book pages ---------- //

  const handleClick = async (page) => {

    ...

    // Resolve the promise to indicate completion of the page flip
    return Promise.resolve();
  };
```

and in the turnPages function:

```
  const turnPages = async (page) => {
    for (let i = 2; i < page; i += 2) {
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 900)); // Wait for 900ms
      await handleClick(i); // Wait for handleClick to complete
      console.log(i);
    }
  };
```

Why is the handleClick function only called once in the first iteration?

EDIT:

As suggested by @Stitt I am now using a new function in case the user clicks an entry in the table of contents. And only doing one page flip animation.

```
// --------------------- Handle Table Of Contents Click -------------------- //

  const handleTocClick = async (page) => {
    // set the pages to be flipped
    setFlippedPages((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      ["2"]: "backward",
      ["3"]: "backward",
    }));
    // Wait for the page flip transition to be half complete
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 450));
    setCurrentPage(page);
  };
```

And I removed the Turn Pages function completely.
Thank! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this issue is due to you attempting to make multiple changes to the state in a single render (see the documentation for [useState](https://react.dev/learn/state-a-components-memory)). The first time you call `handleClick`, it will execute your code for the right-page block, concluding with the `setCurrentPage(page + 2);` line. This change will not be affected, however, until your `turnPages` function has completed, meaning that you are still computing based on the old value of `currentPage`.

In order to fix this issue, I'd suggest writing a new function for when the user enters the page number they wish to view, which will **not** rely on `handleClick`. Note that these issues with `useState` will also apply to your `setFlippedPages` function, so you might be in for a semi-significant re-write in order for this to work for multiple pages. Perhaps a different animation will work better, or simply a single page flip animation which jumps directly to the page entered.

Comment: Thanks!!!

I think that was it. for the case the user clicks on a entry in the table of contents. I am now using a new function and just a single page flip. 

I put the new function on the bottom of my question.